# A probability word problem

Tags: probability, permutations

There is an infinite rectangular window, with infinite vertical iron bars dividing it at distances of 30 centimetres. Now, a 15 cm long pen is randomly thrown at the window. Assuming that the pen can only rotate in the plane parallel to the window, calculate the probability that the pen hits a vertical bar.
(Assume the width of the pen and the bars to be negligible).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So if the centre of the pen is a distance $d$ from the nearest bar, and the pen makes an angle $\theta$ to the vertical at the moment it passes through the plane of the bars, then it will hit iff $7.5\cos\theta>d$. So you just need to do a couple of integrations.

Comment: @almagest Is $d$ measured from the centre of mass of the pen?

Comment: Yes, because it rotates about its cm (which you assume is at its midpoint).

Comment: This is what I thought about- the pen has to be placed anywhere between the point where the head of the pen touches the bar and the point where the tail of the pen touches the bar. That gives the length as 15cosx*2. The total length in which it can be situated is the distance between the bar on its left and on it's right which is 60. So the probability should be 30cosx/60 which is equal to cosx/2 where x varies from 0 to 360 (including each every decimal degree also). How am I to perform an integration for the values of x in cosx as an argument with limits 0 to 360 degrees?